# Interpolation of a multivariate function with duplicated 2D abscissa points

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I want to interpolate a function `q[a,b]` I have a data file which has the form `{a,b,q}` a sample is following

```
{{0.51, 0., 0.},
{0.51, 1.041808672472127, 4.895298538040123},
{0.51, 7.851696289441842, 17.70166883635361},
{0.51, 160.22124553764897, 0.0036047722229149396},
{1., 0., 0.},
{1., 0.0408552420577305, 0.19197249168784813},
{1., 0.30790965840948425, 0.6941830916217107},
{1., 6.2831860995156505, 0.0001413636165848997},
{1.49, 0., 0.},
{1.49, 0.030744601346473967, 0.14446414778529987},
{1.49, 4.699877937621654, 0.13709572480365165},
{1.49, 4.728256206201172, 0.00010637969126843464},
{1.98, 0., 0.},
{1.98, 0.027328844349427832, 0.1284140316020065},
{1.98, 4.177716639454909, 0.121864248031978},
{1.98, 4.202942053054388, 0.00009456079758043966}}
```

when I import this file and interpolate it gives error

> ```
> Interpolation::indp: "There are duplicated abscissa points in {{0.51,0.},{0.51`,1.041808672472127`}"
> ```

Any Idea how to interpolate such data file having repetitive abscissa

Comment: If you take a look at `Interpolation` documentation you will see that your input is wrong. `q = {{#, #2}, #3} & @@@ data // Interpolation`

Comment: @Kuba, actually in this case isn't it the documentation that is wrong?  You can use `data // Interpolation` without any problem

Comment: Of course, I do get the message that you will not get decent interpolation because the data isn't on a rectangular grid

Comment: @JasonB You are supposed to be able to do so, but then I'd expect interpolation function domain to be [1-Length@data] and values which are those sublists. The fact it gives the same answer that mine is surprising. Btw, from the error message given by OP it seems that only two columns are provided to `Interpolation` and that's why the error occurs.

Comment: @Kuba, I've always used `Interpolation` this way (I didn't bother to read the documentation first).  So if you do `Interpolation[ {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}....}]` then you get the exact same function as if you did `Interpolation[ {{{x1,y1},z1},{{x2,y2},z2}....}]`.  Don't have old versions lying around to check how far back this behavior goes though.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) to gather all points with the same abscissa coordinates and then take the [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) of all those points.

```
Interpolation[
 Map[
  {#[[1, 1]], Mean[#[[All, 2]]]} &, 
  GatherBy[{{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ data, First]
 ]
 , InterpolationOrder -> 1
 ]
```

Comment: It can be done by discrete data set. but interpolation order is more than 1 cannot be used. in interpolation order 1 I get the curve which is not smooth.

Comment: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported with `InterpolationOrder->1`. Make the abscissa q grid and you can go for higher orders. Read the documentation.

Comment: If *smoothness* is a requirement, please [edit] your questions and say that explicitly.